# Function only returning value at zero index

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

So, I am learning functions and trying to create a function which takes an array as a parameter.

```
function printArray(arr){
    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
        let upperCased = arr[i].toUpperCase();
        return upperCased;
    };
}
const testArray = ['o', 'p'];
printArray(testArray);
```

However, it returns only the first value 'O'

Comment: Because you use `return` which exit from your function

Comment: remove the return statement and instead put ``console.log(upperCased)``

Answer (score 0):

A return statement only gets executed once, then you exit the function.

Answer (score 0):

You need to update the element on each iteration and, once the loop is complete, return the updated array.

```js
function printArray(arr) {
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    arr[i] = arr[i].toUpperCase();
  }
  return arr;
}

const testArray = ['o', 'p', 'Bob from accounting'];

console.log(printArray(testArray));
```